# Return type for this scala method : String vs Any

Tags: scala

```
 def loop2 (arr: List[String]) : List[String]= {
   arr.map(ele =>
      if (ele.startsWith("2")) ele)
 }
```

I thought that the method should return a List[String], but compiler says it should return List[Any].

Anonymous function inside the map can return either a String or nothing, so that means the the output can be empty list or List[String].

Please explain why return type should be List[Any]

Comment: The title is like Godzilla vs Mothra! Except Any is Godzilla.

Comment: why the down vote?? I was trying to understand why i could not use String as return type and have to use Any.

Comment: Anonymous downvoters who add nothing to the conversation are a blight on SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to filter out the elements that don't start with `"2"` ? If that is the case, you should use `filter`:

```
def loop2(arr: List[String]): List[String] = arr.filter(e => e.startsWith("2"))
```

Or

```
def loop2(arr: List[String]): List[String] = arr.filter(_.startsWith("2"))
```

The problem with the anonymous function `ele => if (ele.startsWith("2")) ele)` is that you don't handle the `else` case. An `if` without the `else` automatically makes the `else` return `Unit`, which then forces the common type to be `Any`.

As seen in the [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

> A short form of the conditional expression eliminates the else-part. The conditional expression if (e1) e2 is evaluated as if it was if (e1) e2 else ().

Comment: While your answer is correct in its first part, it's slightly misleading in that the inferred type is `Unit`. It's `AnyVal` actually. In general, `Unit` can't be an upper bound of any other type(s) because it has no subclasses.

Comment: @cdshines You're right in that it's not inferred, but the compiler automatically fills it in with `Unit`. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You need an `else` with your `if` for the compiler to figure out the type you're talking about.  As it stands, it assumes the else side is `()` so the only deducible type is `Any`.

```
def loop2 (arr: List[String]) : List[String]= {
   arr.map(ele => if (ele.startsWith("2")) ele else "")
 }
```

It seems you're actually trying to filter:

```
def loop2 (arr: List[String]) : List[String]= {
   arr.filter(ele => ele.startsWith("2"))
 }
```

Or even more idiomatically:

```
def loop2 (arr: List[String]) : List[String]= {
   arr.filter(_.startsWith("2"))
}
```